# Time Picker is not working and getting crashed

Tags: android, timepicker, timepickerdialog

I am trying to open Time Picker Dialog in Edit Text. though dialog open successfully but when i click ok to set time it throws **Exception** and getting crash.

Error is as follows:

```
2020-10-06 10:16:28.972 1821-3134/? E/InputReader: isBtnTouch is true need to clear slots.2020-10-06 10:16:29.029 11973-11973/com.example.visitortracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.visitortracker, PID: 11973
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid era
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2686)
    at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3402)
    at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1761)
    at java.util.Calendar.getTime(Calendar.java:1734)
    at com.example.visitortracker.VisitorEntryActivity$1.onTimeSet(VisitorEntryActivity.java:102)
    at android.app.TimePickerDialog.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:174)
    at android.app.TimePickerDialog$1.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:156)
```

**My code is as below**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.edt_timeIn:
            openTimePicker();
            break;
    }
}


private void openTimePicker() {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(VisitorEntryActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selected_hour, int selected_minute) {
            String am_pm = "am";
            if (selected_hour > 12) {
                selected_hour = selected_hour - 12;
                am_pm = "pm";
            }
            calendar.set(hour, selected_hour);
            calendar.set(minute, selected_minute);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
            edt_timeIn.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()) + " " + am_pm);
        }
    }, hour, minute, false);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`calendar.set(hour, selected_hour);` to `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selected_hour);`

and

`calendar.set(minute, selected_minute);` to `calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selected_minute);`

Comment: Thank you so much for response. Its working. can you tell me why its throwing invalid era exception.

Comment: I think because hour and minute are still NULL, you can try printing them.